# How to display data on hmtl5 page?

Tags: jquery, html

My html5 code is

```
     <div id="tablpolicy" align="middle">
                    <div class="policydiv">
                        <div class="left">
                            <span>Policy No.</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <label for="policyno" data-inline="true" id="policylbl"></label> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="policydiv">
                        <div class="left">
                            <span>Quote No.</span> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <label for="quoteno" data-inline="true" id="quotelbl"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="policydiv">
                        <div class="left">
                            <span>Product Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <label for="productname" id="productlbl"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

and my jquery code is

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"webservices.xml",
        contentType:"text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(data){
  var renewpolicy=  $(data).find("renewpolicy");
            var quotenumber=$(renewpolicy).find("QuoteNumber").text();
            var policyno=$(renewpolicy).find("PolicyNumber").text();
            var custid=$(renewpolicy).find("custid").text();
            var productname=$(renewpolicy).find("ProductName").text();
}
})
```

i parsed xml file and get quotenumber,policyno,custid,productname value.Now i want to disply these tags value on the above respective labels in the table.How to set these xml tags value to the abobe labels and which event should i have to use?can we use any query string for this? please help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your code is not HTML5 as long as you use `align` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the success callback put the following.

```
$("#quotelbl").html(quotenumber);
$("#policylbl").html(policyno);
$("#productlbl").html(productname);
```

I can't see where your customerId label is though.

`$("#quotelbl")` is the jQuery selector. Here you put the name of your label with a hash in front.

`.html()` this is a jQuery function that either returns the html of an attribute, or if you pass a value into it, sets the html.

Comment: as @moonwave99 mentioned, it would be more preferable to use templating. I'd recommend Knockout - http://knockoutjs.com/, though it might be a bit of a learning curve if you have little jQuery experience and only want to achieve something simple.

Comment: wel i dont want to know that how to display data on the label..i want to know that on which event will assign data to label so that it can display on the table

Comment: means which event i have to use like pageload,document.ready(function
() etc

Comment: In the success function, where you declare your 4 variables. Do it just below that.

Answer (score 1):

In `success` callback function add at the end `$(`your_selector`).html(`your_text`)`.

In you case you should use:

```
$('#policylbl').html( policyno );
$('#quotelbl').html( quotenumber );
$('#productlbl').html( productname );
```

You should decide what to do with the `custid` variable.

Comment: my issue is not with custid that i will manage.My only issue is on which event i assign value to table so that it can disply on the page.Actualy on button click i naviage to the page where i design this table.Now i want to display parsing data on these labels.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hear about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), then:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"webservices.xml",
    success: function(data){

        var renewpolicy =  $(data).find("renewpolicy");
        $('#policylbl').text( renewpolicy );

    }
});
```

Anyway I do not advice you to go this way - it's better to generate **all** the markup in the success callback [via templating] than injecting values in empty elements.

By the way you state your request format to be in `contentType:"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"`, but you aren't providing any request body [i.e. parameters], so get over it.